# Memory, Stack and 64 bit

Tags: macos, gdb, 64-bit, x86-64, memory-address

On a x86 system a memory location can hold 4 bytes (32 / 8) of data, therefore a single memory address in a 64 bit system can hold 8 bytes per memory address. When examining the stack in GDB though this doesn't appear to be the case, example:

```
0x7fff5fbffa20: 0x00007fff5fbffa48  0x0000000000000000
0x7fff5fbffa30: 0x00007fff5fbffa48  0x00007fff857917e1
```

If I have this right then each hexadecimal pair (48) is a byte, thus the first memory address 
0x7fff5fbffa20: is actually holding 16 bytes of data and not 8.

This has had me really confused and has for a while, so absolutely any input is vastly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: on both x86 and x64 the minimum addressable entity is a byte: each "memory location" contains one byte, in each case. What you are seeing from GDB is only formatting: it is dumping 16 contiguous bytes, as the address increasing from ....20 to ....30, (on the left) indicates.

Long answer: 32bit or 64bit is used to indicate many things, in an architecture: almost always, is the addressable size (how many bits are in an address = how much memory you can directly address - again, *bytes* of memory). It also usually indicates the dimension of registers, and also (but not always) the native word size. 
That means that usually, even if you can address a single byte, the machine works "better" using data of different (longer) size. What "better" means is beyond the question; a little background, however, is good to understand some misconceptions about word size in the question.

Comment: OK, why is it increasing from 20 - 30 if it is showing 16 bytes? Surely it should increase from 20 - 36? And why does GDB show 16 bytes, I mean is there any particular reason or just to make it easier to read?

Comment: @JamesParker 20-30 = 10, in hex, or 16 in decimal

Comment: @JamesParker and yes, it shows it in groups of 16 to make it easier to read. You can even change that: for example, if you print memory content with "x", you can specify how to represent it (http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/gdb/gdb_56.html)

Comment: Ah, awesome. Thanks a lot guys that's cleared up a hell of a lot :)

Comment: Examples of "strange" :) architectures: 80286 (16 bit chip with 24 bit addressing) or Motorola 68000 and Intel 386SX, which are the opposite (32 bit registers and word size, 24 bit addressing)